# Pre-Caching large files

Tags: memory, cache, ram

I have a CPython routine which is time critical, it reads large binary files to generate dynamic spectrum, it's slower if the files are not cached previously. When I use `vmtouch` to pre-cache, it takes ~14-16 secs to cache the complete 2 GB file, for the first file, but is slower for the next file (takes ~52 seconds).

1. As the routine needs two 2 GB files for processing, is there any way of pre-caching these files, reasonably faster?

Details about the system:

Volatile memory : 16GB
Ubuntu version  : 18.04.5 LTS

**First file `vmtouch` output**

```
vmtouch -vt First_Large_binary.bin
[OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO] 512000/512000

Files: 1
Directories: 0
Touched Pages: 512000 (1G)
Elapsed: 14.896 seconds
```

**Second file `vmtouch` output**

```
vmtouch -vt Second_Large_binary.bin
[OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO] 512000/512000

Files: 1
Directories: 0
Touched Pages: 512000 (1G)
Elapsed: 52.126 seconds
```

Comment: @thanasisp The question is more on ways to cache files (quickly) on linux. Though, I am currently using vmtouch, I am open for using any other tool which can do this job. I have added python tag as I am using a python - cython based routine to do the processing, but I guess it's correct that it is not relevant here.

Comment: vmtouch can daemonize and lock files into RAM: `vmtouch -dl /binary or /directory` - have you tried it?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for the suggestion!  But, since I have to use different binary files every-time, I cannot lock a set of these files into RAM.                       Each of these files are of 2 GB, and in most cases, I will be processing at-least 10 pairs of such files, each file set at a time. This requires me to cache two 2 GB files, then process it, free the cache and load next file set, and process again.

Comment: Seeing that you're doing some serious stuff maybe your company could sponsor you with a new PC for you? Modern PCs can contain up to 128GB of RAM - must be enough for you.

Comment: Did you considered copy and run it from a tmpfs filesystem? (ramdisk). I maded a simple script that created, copied and run a near-real time script. Also consider increasing the priority of the process by starting it with a nice level of 0... i don't recommend you to start by negative values